# Bloc listener is not triggered after changing the state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

It is interesting, that I have created a bloc like this:

```
@injectable
@singleton
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final IAuthService _authService;

  LoginBloc(this._authService) : super(const LoginState()) {
    ....

  FutureOr<void> _registerWithEmail(
      _RegisterWithEmail event, Emitter<LoginState> emit) async {
   
      emit(state.copyWith(status: StateStatus.success));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: StateStatus.failure));
    }
  }
}
```

and I am using it on material:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => getIt<LoginBloc>(),
      child: MaterialApp.router(
```

when the application is launched I will go to the home page, There is a button here,

```
 DefaultTextButton(
                onTap: () =>  context.goNamed(RouteConstants.register);
```

After pressing the page is moved to the register page:

```
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailCtl = TextEditingController();
    final passwordCtl = TextEditingController();
    final confirmPasswordCtl = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ModColors.purple,
      body: BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.status == StateStatus.success) {
            context.pushNamed(RouteConstants.login);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
```

here I am using listener to catch state change, In this page I a have a button too, after tapping on the button I will execute a method inside login bloc:

```
ElevatedButton(
     radius: 24,
      fixedSize: const Size(344, 48),
      onTap: () async => getIt<LoginBloc>()
      .add(LoginEvent.registerInWithEmail(...
      )),
```

but after calling emit: `emit(state.copyWith(status: StateStatus.success));`the `listener`is not called? I have check state, it is changed to new on:

```
 LoginBloc Change { currentState: LoginState(status: StateStatus.initial), nextState: LoginState(status: StateStatus.success) }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps it’s an object equality problem. Look into equatable package.

Comment: it is related to get it, I have changed to bloc whiteout get it injector, and everything is fine but when I am using get it to get login bloc, it seems I will receive a new instance, although I am using a singleton, but I don't know somehow I receive new instance of login bloc.@MatthewTrent

Comment: do you register your singleton in main with getIt.registerSingleton¡, also if you are actually using getIt as your DI then you should use BlocProvider.value because its not created in the widget tree, is created by getIt

Comment: I am using an injector, so I guess I don't need to change sth, I need to add a @singleton annotation. so I did it  .

Comment: After some reading I see singleton implements injectable so you don't need the double annotation, can you upload your main and your  generated file to see if they're created as should be